# How to match two column data and show value from another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two Excel sheets.

First:

| Number | Name | Remarks | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jhon | 5 | Good |
| 2 | Doe | 4 | Better |
| 3 | Alex | 3 | Poor |

Second:

| Number | Name | Result | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | 3 | Poor |
| 2 | Dave |  |  |
| 3 | Jhon | 5 | Poor |

In second sheet, I will put name column value, and it will match with the first sheet name column value. If matches then second sheet Result, Remarks will update the first sheet result and remarks. If no match then result and remarks will be null.

How can I do that in Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `XLOOKUP()`.

```
=XLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4,"",0)
```

Also can try any of below-

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$4,2,FALSE),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4,0)),"")
=FILTER(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4=B2,"")
```

[image]

Comment: There something error. I have updated my question, can you please check

Comment: What error you are getting?